Does functional calculus commute with *-morphisms in $C^*$-algebras?
Our teaching assistant claimed the following. If you are in a let's say commutative $C^*$-algebras $X,Y$ and a linear $*$-morphism $\varphi:X\to Y$, let $x\in X$ and let $f\in C(\text{sp} (x),\mathbb{C})$. Then our teaching assistant claimed that $f(\varphi(x))=\varphi(f(x))$, where the action of $f$ on $x$ is defined by functional calculus. Since the algebras are commutative, one can define consider $X$ and $Y$ to be continuous functions of some compact set to $\mathbb{C}$ and $f(g)$ as $f\circ g$. I really don't see why $f$ and $\varphi$ should commute. I've tried looking for a counterexample, but didn't really find one.

First show it for polynomials and then approximate

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Thanks that makes sense!
